# create easing function programmatically C#

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard, easing-functions

I am learning how to create animations with C#. so if I am animating the margin of an object for example then I would use the following method to animate its margin:

```
test(someObject, FrameworkElement.MarginProperty);

/// <summary>
/// animate margin of an object
/// </summary>
/// <param name="target">what object do you whant to animate?</param>
/// <param name="property">what property do you want to animate</param>
public void test(DependencyObject target, DependencyProperty property)
{
    ThicknessAnimation animation = new ThicknessAnimation();
    animation.To = new Thickness(0,0,0,0);   // final value

    //animation.From = new Thickness(50,50,50,50);

    //make animation last 5 seconds
    animation.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
    animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

    // set the ease function
    BounceEase b = new BounceEase();
    animation.EasingFunction = b;

    //note that I would like to add an easeIn function

    //start animating
    Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, target);  // what object will be animated?
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(property)); // what property will be animated
    Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
    sb.Children.Add(animation);
    sb.Begin();
}
```

note that I am able to create a ease function. But what if I want to create an EaseInOut easing function. what do I have to add to my test method in order to animate the object using an EaseInOut approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess I finally got my method working in order to animate the margin of an object.

```
MyStoryboards.Animations a = new MyStoryboards.Animations();

// set the ease function
BounceEase b = new BounceEase();
b.Bounces = 5;
b.Bounciness = 1;
b.EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseIn;

a.animThickness(tv, FrameworkElement.MarginProperty, tv.Margin, new Thickness(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), b);
```

...

...

```
public void animThickness(DependencyObject target, DependencyProperty property, Thickness from, Thickness to, TimeSpan beginTime, TimeSpan duration , IEasingFunction e)
{
    ThicknessAnimation animation = new ThicknessAnimation();
    animation.To = to;   // final value

    animation.From = from;

    animation.BeginTime = beginTime;
    animation.Duration = duration;

    animation.EasingFunction = e;

    //start animating
    Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, target);  // what object will be animated?
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(property)); // what property will be animated
    Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
    sb.Children.Add(animation);
    sb.Begin();
}
```